# Embedding global content variable values in Drupal content

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

A customer of mines wants the ability in their Drupal site to set some variables which they will embed in content. You know, things like number of customers, number of branches and so on. This way, when they update the variable values, the changes ripple throughout the site without them having to go and update a bunch of pages.

Have any of you come across a module which can handle this?

Many thanks

Froogle.

Answer (score 3):

[Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) combined with [Token Filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) - it's fairly easy to setup your own tokens and instruct your content managers on how to use them using the Token Filter module.

Comment: Thank you so much Mirzu. I'll take a look at those in action - from what I saw on the modules pages they certainly do appear to fit the bill.

Comment: some other related module links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138005/could-i-add-some-variables-into-the-drupal-node-body