# could i add some variables into the drupal node body?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

when i create an article useing the story type,could i add some variables into the body's textarea.then can invoke the variable and output it. thank you.
the drupal version is 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting textual placeholders to be replaced by actual values on render is the purpose of the [filters system](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-input-formats-and-filters) in Drupal. [Token filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) provides, well, [token](http://drupal.org/project/token) replacement and is an handy tools if your need replacement for tokenized values. But there are [plenty of filters for Drupal 6.x](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=tid:63%20drupal_core:87%20bs_project_sandbox:0&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc) and you can even [define your own](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_filter/6) in a [custom module](http://drupal.org/node/231276). The [Custom filter](http://drupal.org/project/customfilter) can help for this. You can also use token filter and define your own token in your custom module.

A simple solution is to use the PHP filter but this is a insecure way of doing it. Also, putting PHP code in node (or any content) is a maintenance nightmare and a bad habits. You would be better doing it properly from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Contrib modules would be the way to go, unless you feel comfortable with PHP in which case you can just use the PHP filter. Depending on what variables you need you can try one of:
http://drupal.org/project/InsertNode and http://drupal.org/project/token_filter

There are a couple of others (I like insert view) but they're currently not marked for production use.